# Updating object with useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm using React right now and I'm struggling with updating a state object.

I defined a state variable and filled it with an object:

```
const [connections, setConnections] = useState({...platformConnections})
```

Now I want to update this state object with setConnections(). But when I try something like this:

```
setConnections({connectionA: {connected: true}})
```

it just updates the entire object when I log it.

How can I update this state variable and keep the other values from before the update?

Comment: `setConnections(prev => ({ ...prev, connectionA: { ...prev.connectionA, connected: true } }))`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Updating just part of state and keeping others same when using useState hook](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59296317/1541563)

Answer (score 2):

Calling `setConnections` will set an entire new value to `connections`, it's your responsibility to make sure you keep the values you are not updating.

For example, if you set a string like this:

```
setConnections('new value')
```

Now, `connections` will have `new value` instead of an object. That being said, in order to keep previous values you will have to either use `Object.assign` or the spread operator `...`.

```
setConnections({
  ...connections,
  connectionA: { ...connections.connectionA, connected: true }
})
```

That will work in most cases, however there are some edge cases where the value of `connections` might be changing frequently and given that `setConnections` runs async, you might not be getting the current values and therefore you might lose some data, to prevent this problem you can use a function to get the current state first and then set the values you need.

```
setConnections(prev => ({
   ...prev,
   connectionA: { ...prev.connectionA, connected: true }
  })
)
```

In this case `prev` has the current values on any given time, and you can safely assign whatever you need.

Comment: Just one nitpick, this isn't a "rest operator" or "spread operator", it's [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax). The distinction is that an "operator" has a distinct return value, but this is just a syntactic expression that requires context for meaning, the context being `[...iterable]`, `{ ...object }`, or `f(...iterable)`. Good thorough explanation otherwise though.

Answer (score 0):

What you have done is overwritten the state with just `{connectionA: {connected: true}}`

Please see https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates

For updating state based on prev values along with the help of the spread operator

```
setConnectitions ( prevConnections => ({
  ...prevConnections,
  connectionA: {...prevConnections.connectionA ,connected : true}
}));
```

In the above, prevConnections prop uses the previous state and then creates a new obj using spread operator which is the three dots ...  and then overwrite the property you want to modify and set the value.